# can we override Apache CXF generated HTML page

Tags: java, rest, cxf

can we override Apache CXF generated HTML page

i tried

```
    <init-param>        
        <param-name>hide-service-list-page</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>         
    </init-param>
```

but it shows "No service was found" instead of showing this how can we show different html page.
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain further? Do you when to save service description html page?

Comment: For Example  URL is http://localhost:8080/UserDetails it will list all the "Available SOAP services:" and "Available RESTful services:" so, instead of these list i want to show some other messages.

Answer (score 1):

Apache cxf use a class called `FormattedServiceListWriter` to generate the html page that you are talking about, you can take a look of the code [here](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/a36af6323505211479c875fb9923cc6dcbc6ac95/rt/transports/http/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/transport/servlet/servicelist/FormattedServiceListWriter.java).

What you can do to personalize that page is to create a class in your project with the exact same name in the same package `org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.servicelist` (you have to create that package in your project also), and change the `writeServiceList` method for your own implementation, that class will have priority over the one in the cxf jar

new `FormattedServiceListWriter` class

```
  package org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.servicelist;

  /*--imports--*/

  public class FormattedServiceListWriter implements ServiceListWriter {

      /*... this remains the same as in the original class*/

      public void writeServiceList(PrintWriter writer,
                                   String basePath,
                                   AbstractDestination[] soapDestinations,
                                   AbstractDestination[] restDestinations) throws IOException {

          /*this is the method you should change*/

          writer.write("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" "
                       + "\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">");
          writer.write("<HTML><HEAD>");
          writer.write("<LINK type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"" + styleSheetPath + "\">");
          writer.write("<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">");
          if (title != null) {
              writer.write("<title>" + title + "</title>");
          } else {
              writer.write("<title>CXF - Service list</title>");
          }
          writer.write("</head><body>");


          writer.write("<span class=\"heading\">WHATEVER YOU WANT TO PUT HERE</span>");

          writer.write("</body></html>");
      }

      /*... this remains the same as in the original class*/

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your **web.xml** to override the service list path

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>service-list-path</param-name>
  <param-value>/*</param-value>
</init-param>
```